# Can i have a step by step rotation with quaternion?

Tags: c++, quaternions

Here i put my code that i develop to take the rotation of a mobile phone. Data aqusition is made with Android API Rotation_vector_type==quaternion
Thank you.

```
while (fscanf(f, "%lf %lf %lf %lf", &val1, &val2, &val3, &val4)!=EOF)
    {
        cont++;

        b.x = val1;
        b.y = val2;
        b.z = val3;
        b.w = val4;

        quaternion rez;

        rez.w = newRotation.w * b.w - newRotation.x * b.x - newRotation.y * b.y - newRotation.z * b.z;  // 1
        rez.x = newRotation.w * b.x + newRotation.x * b.w + newRotation.y * b.z - newRotation.z * b.y;  // i
        rez.y = newRotation.w * b.y - newRotation.x * b.z + newRotation.y * b.w + newRotation.z * b.x;  // j
        rez.z = newRotation.w * b.z + newRotation.x * b.y - newRotation.y * b.x + newRotation.z * b.w;  // k
        newRotation = rez;
    }
    cout << newRotation.x << " " << newRotation.y << " " << newRotation.z << " " << newRotation.w << endl;
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: what to do to have anytime my rotation ?